# mySQL - Correct Way to Do this?

Tags: mysql, database

I guess you can I'm an old fart, but been YEARS I did mySQL (not an expert myself though), I'm pretty sure there are better way to write this.  Hopefully you could help me on this.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MIN(bank_id) FROM bank) AS MinBank,
    (SELECT MAX(bank_id) FROM bank) AS MaxBank,
    (SELECT bank_id FROM bank WHERE bank_id = $UserID) AS OldBankID,
    (SELECT bank_name FROM bank WHERE bank_id = OldBankID) AS OldBankName,
    (SELECT bank_interest FROM bank WHERE bank_id = OldBankID) AS OldBankInterest,
    (SELECT bank_fees FROM bank WHERE bank_id = OldBankID) AS OldBankFees,
    (SELECT bank_pic_url FROM bank WHERE bank_id = OldBankID) AS BankPic
    (SELECT bank_id FROM bank HAVING bank_id > (SELECT bank_id FROM users WHERE uid = $UserID) LIMIT 1) AS NewBankID,
    (SELECT bank_name FROM bank WHERE bank_id = NewBankID) AS NewBankName,
    (SELECT bank_interest FROM bank WHERE bank_id = NewBankID) AS NewBankInterest,
    (SELECT bank_fees FROM bank WHERE bank_id = NewBankID) AS NewBankFees,
    (SELECT bank_cost FROM bank WHERE bank_id = NewBankID) AS NewBankCost,
FROM dwrel_bank LIMIT 1
```

Basically it's 2 Tables:
(users) Table 1 - Retrieve Bank_ID (Customer's Old ID)
(bank) Table 2 - Get their OLD Bank Information AND Retrieve their NEXT "Upgrade" availability.

It does give me the information I wanted, but wanted to see if I could improve this somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: Its confusing, in one place you get old bank id from `bank table` in another you get it from `users table`

Comment: Basically this:  Get Bank_ID from the User's table.

Then use this bank_id and get information from the bank table. However from the bank table, I wanted 2 "repeated" information from the same bank table: Their CURRENT bank information and their NEXT potential "upgrade".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the first part based on oldBankId as below

```
 select bank_id OldBankId ,bank_name OldBankName, bank_interest OldBankInterest ,
 bank_fees OldBankFees, bank_pic_url as BankPic from bank
 where bank_Id =(select bank_id from bank where bank_id= $user_id)
```

you have to join this with the newBank Id and use the same syntax as above

Comment: when you say join, do you mean UNION or LEFT JOIN?  not quite sure.

Comment: Use left join on `id = (select id from table where id >$userId limit 1)`

Comment: hope you could show the way, I got a bit lost trying it myself haha, thanks in advance :)